# Django - document.querySelector finds the base.html tags only

Tags: javascript, django

I have the django app with traditional base.html approach, which is extended in every other template. However, I have a problem with reaching out html tags which are outside the base.html template.

```
var myHeading = document.querySelector(".contentfont");
console.log(myHeading);
```

gives me:

```
<div class="contentfont">          
<!-- JS -->
<script src="/static/js/squad_picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h1 id="test" class="heading test"> test page </h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron"> 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

but when I try for example

```
var myHeading = document.querySelector(".contentfont > h1");
```

it always gives me null. The same happens while trying to access anything which is not inside base.html directly by id or class.

I add the part of base.html:

```
 <div class="contentfont">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

and the html which is extending it:

```
 {% extends 'my_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!-- JS -->
<script src="{% static 'js/squad_picker.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h1 id='test' class="heading test">test page </h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  tag should be at the end of the html file...